# Interface to sense 5kV through microcontroller GPIO

Tags: microcontroller, high-voltage, sensing

I want to sense the DC voltage of a capacitor from 0V to 5kV. I need to sense that with a standard 5V powered microcontroller GPIO. I need that the solution doesn't dissipate too much heat and it must be reasonably compact.

I can think of using either a transformer or simply a voltage divider to adjust voltage levels to the dynamic range of the microcontroller input, but I have a hunch that there are more elegant and compact ways of solving it.

I have not a found specific solutions for this, or ICs that handle these levels.

Isolated solutions are preferable.

Comment: Do you need to "sense" the full range of 0 - 5 kV in a linear manner with an ADC? Or in a binary manner, whether it's there or not?

Comment: Exactly how much discharge on the capacitor are you willing to tolerate; i.e. how much conductance is the sensor allowed to present to the capacitor?

Comment: There is no DC transformer, therefore you should not waste your time thinking about it.

Comment: For a resistive voltage divider you need an analog input with very low input current. If you prefer an isolated solution, you should digitize the analog voltage at first and then transmit the binary data serially over an optocoupler.

Comment: Describe the capacitor, both physically and in terms of capacity, and define EXACTLY what you mean by "reasonably compact". "Reasonably" is not remotely descriptive without far more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to sense the DC voltage of a capacitor from 0V to 5kV.

...

> I can think of using either a transformer

If you think transformers work for stepping down DC then maybe you shouldn't be working with 5kV yet.

---

Your question isn't clear enough. Do you want to MEASURE? Or do you want to just threshold a single level?

Because if you just need to threshold a single level you can just use a diode clamp with current limiting resistor and feed that to a comparator, all of which can operate off an isolated power supply and transmit the compartor output via optocoupler to the GPIO.

---

But if you want to measure, and your talking about "adjusting dynamic range" implies this, then it is isn't going to work anyways if you limit yourself to a single GPIO because you need extra pins to adjust the dynamic range. Just use those to control an ADC and build a differential probe:

https://circuitcellar.com/research-design-hub/high-voltage-differential-probe/

The summary for the differntial probe is:

1. Step down BOTH positive and negative terminals with a resistive
   divider
2. Add a capacitive divider in parallel so the RC time constant formed by the resistive divider and parasitic input capacitances doesn't create a low pass filter to interfere with your signal.
3. Feed both inputs to a low-noise (i.e. JFET input) differential amplifier to recover the signal and rescale it to your output voltage range.
4. The capacitive divider works by adding a parallel capacitance to each of the differential amplifier's inputs to swamp out and dominate their capacitance. That gives you a known capacitance for the lower leg of the divider so you can select the capacitance of the upper leg. Then you add in the upper leg capacitors and add in a small variable capcaitor to tune things out so they match perfectly. You can do add a small variable resistor to tune the resistor divider too but resistors are much tighter tolerance than capacitors so it is not as necessary.
5. Use multiple capacitors and resistors in series in the dividers to attain the required voltage ratings and to prevent against single component failures from allowing enough high voltage through to blow everything.

Since your application is just measuring a capacitor voltage level you may be able to omit some parts.

- For instance, maybe you don't care about frequency response so you
  can omit the capacitive divider.
- Since it's not a bipolar measurement, if the capacitor shares the same ground as
  your MCU ground (though this presents other safety issues such as a 5kV supply having a fairly easy path through a single-failed capacitor to get to your logic) then you might be able to omit the circuitry on the negative leg of the probe. The reason this negative leg exists is so you can measure signals that do not share the same ground as the ADC but if this isn't required and you omit the negative leg then you also don't need to amplify it with a
  differential amplifier to recover the signal. You can just straight up step it down and follow it with a buffer before feeding to the ADC since for safety the resistances involved in the divider are going to be very very high. However, when you do this there is no protective resistance in the negative leg anymore but in this case, you could instead run it through analog isolator after stepping it down.

You could also potentially use a voltage-to-frequency converter instead of an ADC. That would be easily isolated and allow true measurement with a single GPIO.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my proposed circuit.  It shows an ATtiny85 as an example of µController but any ADC input is suitable. The OpAmp is good for a single 5V supply. The OpAmp output will go from 1V to 4V with an input span from -5kV to +5KV. On a 10 bits ADC the resolution is +-5V.

[image]

Some time ago I made a similar probe with adjusted resistors to match my Fluke meter input impedance. I am using it for high voltage measurements. Nothing fancy in term of accuracy but suitable for most jobs.

[image]
[image]

Resistors are in line into a plastic tube for insulation.
Warning: 5000 V is dangerous. Be careful.

Comment: Is that circuit self-powered? I'm having trouble figuring out what's going on around the inverting input. Like what's that vertical line running straight down from the inverting input? And the bottom left diode?

Comment: @DKNguyen I think that's the negative power supply rail.

Comment: @DKNguyen, this is the ground from the 5V-GND supply for the uController power supply. This circuit is simply an inverting current to voltage converter. The OpAmp see a 2.5V (virtual zero) on the +input and will send adequate current feedback on the - input such that is satisfy the OpAmp for a zero volt between + and - input. Doing so will provide a voltage at the output from 1volt up to 4volts based on an input of -5kV to +5kV. The two diodes make sure that the input never goes out of the range GND<->V+5V.  Which means, if one could measure the voltage on the probe, it would be +2.5V.

Comment: But reading this wouldpractically be pretty much impossible for the total resistance of the probe is 22meg time 20 = 440megs. I dont know of a meter capable of reading 2.5V out of a source with impedance 440megs.

Comment: the bottom left diode is also a 1N4148.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard without discharging it.

### Resistive method

Basically a divider. 5kV to 5V means higher than 1000:1 conversion.

There should be enough current flowing through the divider so that the input current of the ADC pin can be neglected.

For example, using a divider with 10M and 10k resistors will bring 4.995V. The current flowing through the divider will be 0.5mA which is a reasonable value. The dissipation will be \$P=(5000)^2/10010000=2.5W\$ and more than %90 of this dissipation will come from the 10M resistor. So, taking the voltage rating of the resistors into account, you may have to connect tens of resistors in series to to deal with the heat and voltage.

Another problem is discharging. Assuming the capacitor is 1 μF, if the measurement with an ADC takes 1 ms then the the capacitor will discharge to 4.999 kV. The longer the measurement takes the higher the discharge. To make the discharge amount less you need to increase the divider resistors but this is not good for the ADC as the noise and therefore the inaccuracy will be much greater. Plus, since the net resistance of the divider (basically the parallel of them) should be low enough to be neglected w.r.t. the input impedance of the ADC, the inaccuracy will be greater.

So you may want to use a buffer (basically an op amp with nA or even pA bias currents) to decrease the discharge amount further.

### Complex method

I just wanted to post this here. I know, it'll be a terrible idea to measure a charged capacitor but still, it's an idea.

Basically, the method involves DC-AC conversion. A 1000:1 transformer can be fed by a HF bridge which consists of 10 kV SiC MOSFETs. The transformer should be large enough, and the wires insulation should be thick enough to provide enough isolation. Even TIWs may not be enough for 5 kV.

Comment: Thick wires are used for high currents. For high voltages wires with thick insulation should be used.

Comment: @Uwe that's what I meant actually. Thanks for pointing out.